# Do Graphics Cards with power connectors still draw 75W from the PCIex16 slot?

Tags: graphics-card, motherboard, power-supply, nvidia-graphics-card

The PCIex16 slot on mainboards is specified to supply a maximum Wattage of 75W, so lower end Graphics cards don't need additional power connectors.

What about Graphics Cards that do have one or multiple 6- or 8-pin connectors? Do they still use the power from the slot, or do they rely solely on the power that is supplied directly by the PSU?

---

The specific card in question is the nVidia GTX 970, which - in the reference design - is specified to have a TDP of 150W, and two 6-pin connectors, which can supply 75W each, so that would be enough for the card.

Comment: This entirely depends on the card.  You should follow the installation instructions and read the product's specification for specific power requirements.

Answer (score 2):

It depends on the card. The card is **allowed** to draw up to 75 Watt. It does not need to draw as much as it can.

E.g. A card with a 6 pin PCI-e power connector is allowed to draw up to 150 Watt (75 from ther PCI-e connector and 75 Watt from the 6 pins connector). If it only needs 125 Watts then drawing 75 Watt from the 6 pins connector and 50 Watt via the PCI-e slot on the motherboard is fine.

(I would even say 'preferred' since the path between the PSU and the graphics card is probably a lot shorter, leading to less losses and less heat).